# How to change probability table in object of class bn.fit (bn.fit.dnet) from bnlearn library?

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr, bnlearn

I try to modify object of class `bn.fit` (`bn.fit.dnet`) from R's `bnlearn` library.
I need

1. to set equal probabilities for every row in bn.fit$node$prob table. For this I use next code:

   ```
   library(bnlearn)
   library(purrr)

   data(insurance)

   bn <- tabu(insurance, score = "bic")
   bn_fit <- bn.fit(bn, insurance, method = 'bayes')

   bn_fit[1:length(bn_fit)] <- modify(bn_fit[1:length(bn_fit)], function(node) {
     node$prob <- modify(node$prob, ~(1 / NROW(node$prob)))
     node
   })
   ```

I suppose this approach bit ugly and almost sure there exist more elegant way to do this. I can not remove `1:length(bn_fit)`. Also I don't know why I can not use `NROW(.x)` instead of `NROW(node$prob)` in my code.

2. To set arbitrary distribution on EVERY column in `bn.fit$node$prob` table. I don't understand how to avoid for loops in this case.

Related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610572/conditional-probability-modification-of-one-node-in-bayesian-network-r-code)

Comment: This is moderatley less typing but not in the spirit of using tidy package functions `bn_fit[] =  lapply(bn_fit, function(node) {
  node$prob <- modify(node$prob, ~(1 / NROW(node$prob)))
  node
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (1), `modify` takes a `list` or an `atomic vector`. `bn_fit` is of class `bn.fit, bn.fit.dnet`, however, under the hood it is a `list` too, since calling `typeof()` yields `list`. My guess is that there is no S3 generic method for subsetting these classes so R figures out that it is  essentially a `list` and accordingly strips the class arguments. So subsetting `bn_fit` turns it into `class` `list`, and therefore you can use `modify` on it. Subsetting can even be done with empty brackets `[]`, it will just return the object, but this time as `class` `list`. An alternative that I use below is to "manually" set the `class` attribute to `NULL` via `attr(bnfit, "class") <- NULL`.

Regarding (2), I wrote a `tidyverse` based function which can be used to alter the `prob` table of each node into a `bayesm::rdirichlet` distribution (see code below). The user still needs to provide part of the `alpha` argument (the length argument is given by the length of each prob `table`). Under the hood the function is relying on `purrr::modify`. It takes care of the classes by stripping them first and adding them back once the modification is done. My approach is to turn the prob `table`s into `data.frame`s then modify the `Freq` column and adjust it for existing other variables (groups) and then translate that `data.frame` back into a `table` using `xtabs` and formulation notation via `reformulate`.

I'm not so deep into bayesian networks, so I do not know to what extent this function can be generalized, or whether it only works on the dataset you provided. Further, please test if the modified object is accepted by functions expecting class `bn.fit, bn.fit.dnet`.

I tried to comment each step of my code, but please ask if something is not clear.

(3) Regarding your question why `NROW(.x)` does not work in your code and you have to use NROW(node$prob) instead: This has to do with the way `modify` loops over the prob `table`s. A good way to check over what elements `modify` is looping over is to use `purrr::pluck`.

```r
library(bnlearn)
library(tidyverse)

data(insurance)

bn <- tabu(insurance, score = "bic")
bn_fit <- bn.fit(bn, insurance, method = 'bayes')

change_bn_prob_table <- function(bnfit, alpha) {
  
  # save class attribute of bnfit object
  old_class <- attr(bnfit, "class")
  
  # strip class so that `modify` can be used
  attr(bnfit, "class") <- NULL
  
  # loop over `prop` tables of each node
  new <- purrr::modify(bnfit, function(x) {
    
    # save attributes of x 
    old_x_attr <- attributes(x)
    
    # save attributes of x[["prob"]]
    old_xprob_attr <- attributes(x[["prob"]])
    
    # turn `table` into data.frame
    inp <- as.data.frame(x[["prob"]]) 
    # save names apart from `Freq`
    cnames <- inp %>% select(-Freq) %>% colnames
    
    out <- inp %>% 
      # overwrite column `Freq` with probabilities from bayesm::rdirichlet
      # alpha needs to be supplied (the length of alpha is given by `nrow`)
      mutate(Freq := bayesm::rdirichlet(c(rep(alpha, nrow(inp))))) %>% 
      # devide probilities by sum of Freq in all remaining groups
      group_by(!!! syms(cnames[-1])) %>% 
      mutate(Freq := Freq/sum(Freq)) %>% 
      # turn data.frame back into prob table using formula notation via reformulate
      xtabs(reformulate(paste(colnames(.)), "Freq"), .)
    
    # strip `call` attribute from newly generated prob table
    attr(out, "call") <- NULL  
    # add `class` `table` as attribute
    attr(out, "class") <- "table"
    
    # restore old attribues and write x out to x$prob
    attributes(out) <- old_xprob_attr
    x[["prob"]] <- out
    
    # restore old attribues and return x
    attributes(x) <- old_x_attr
    x
    
  })
  
  # add saved class attributes 
  attr(new, "class") <- old_class
  new
  
}
# here `2` is the first part of `alpha` of `bayesm::rdirichlet`
bn_fit2 <- change_bn_prob_table(bn_fit, 2)

# test that `logLik` can be used on new modified bnfit object 
logLik(bn_fit2, insurance)
#> [1] -717691.8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You can't assign random numbers like that for the probabilities as then the cpt's are not stochastic (although you could if you normalised them after)

Comment: 1) Thank you for bn_fit[] but I need object of class bn.fit not list to use with logLik function  2) Yes all categories should sum up to 1. In particular, I want to use bayesm::rdirichlet distribution. I can only use runif (like you) and have problems with any other distribution

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I will look into it.

Comment: Also I don't know why I can not use `NROW(.x)` instead of `NROW(node$prob)` in my code.

Comment: Thank you for your job @TimTeaFan. This is not exactly what I need because of error in `logLik(bn_fit2, insurance)` but I've fixed your code and got what I want

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `logLik` was not working, I forgot to include a couple of arguments to save and restore the attributes of the list elements the function is working on. I added that code and all should be working now.

Comment: @TimTeaFan could you explain why do you use `rlang` operators in your code?

Comment: @drastega I think the only `rlang` operator I use is `!!! syms` to splice in a vector of colnames as arguments to `group_by`. The number of variables to group by can differ between each node and this is a convenient way to take care of that. Apart from that I have `:=` in my code, but it’s not necessary and can be replaced by `=`.